# Loop through list and pull data from Excel workbooks inside an indicated folder

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am looking for a way to loop through a list and find the corresponding information inside other Excel workbooks that are located inside a folder that only contains Excel files. All of these Excel files are formatted the same.

My code is able to do this with just one number.

I thought about doing a basic loop, where it searches for the first number's information, then loops and looks for the second, but I couldn't get it to work. My code is adapted from ideas that I found on the internet.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strPath = "J:\FILE_PATH\Work Center Rounting Data"
    strSearch = "900491787"

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        Set wOut = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Material # Info Search")
        lRow = 1
        With wOut
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        .Cells(lRow, 5) = "Set Up Time"
        .Cells(lRow, 6) = "Production Time"
        
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
    
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
              (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
              UpdateLinks:=0, _
              ReadOnly:=True, _
              AddToMRU:=False)
    
            For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
                Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
                
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If rFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                       .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                        .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                        .Cells(lRow, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 11).Value
                        .Cells(lRow, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 13).Value
                    End If
                    Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
                Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
            Next
    
            wbk.Close (False)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
    Set wOut = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Instead of a given string search, I want this code to work for numbers in a range of cells on a workbook.

I tried adding this code:

```vb
Sub Test2()
    ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
    Range("A2").Select
    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ' Insert your code here.
    ' Step down 1 row from present location.
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

and replacing `strSearch = "#"` with `strSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Time Template").Range(2, 2)`, and putting `Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(Range("B2").Select)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should be close to what you're looking for:

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()
    Const FLDR_PATH As String = "J:\FILE_PATH\Work Center Rounting Data\" 'cleaner to include the last "\" here...
    
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet, wbk As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Dim itm, c As Range, rwOut As Range
    Dim colSearch As New Collection, colMatches As New Collection, cSrch As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set cSrch = ActiveCell
    Do While Len(cSrch.Value) > 0  'collect all of the search terms
        colSearch.Add cSrch.Value
        Set cSrch = cSrch.Offset(1)
    Loop
    If colSearch.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to look for
    Debug.Print "Collected " & colSearch.Count & " search terms"
    
    Set wOut = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Material # Info Search") 'ThisWorkbook?
    Set rwOut = wOut.Range("A1:F1") 'output row
    
    rwOut.Value = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", "Cell", "Text in Cell", _
                        "Set Up Time", "Production Time")
    
    strFile = Dir(FLDR_PATH & "*.xls*")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        Debug.Print "Opening " & FLDR_PATH & strFile
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FLDR_PATH & strFile, _
                    UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
    
        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
            Debug.Print "    Checking sheet " & wks.name
            For Each itm In colSearch
                'push the Find() loop out to a separate method
                Set colMatches = FindAll(wks.UsedRange, CStr(itm), xlPart) 'or xlWhole
                Debug.Print "       Got " & colMatches.Count & " matches for  " & itm
                If colMatches.Count > 0 Then          'any matches?
                    For Each c In colMatches          'loop over matches
                        Set rwOut = rwOut.Offset(1)   'next output row
                        rwOut.Value = Array(wbk.Name, wks.Name, c.Address, _
                                            c.Value, c.Offset(, 11).Value, _
                                            c.Offset(, 13).Value)
                    Next c
                End If   'got matches
            Next itm     'next search term
        Next wks         'next worksheet
        wbk.Close False
        strFile = Dir()  'next file
    Loop
    wOut.Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub

'Find all matches for `val` in `rng` and return as a Collection of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String, matchType As XlLookAt) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=matchType, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv 'return a collection of any found cells
End Function
```

Comment: I am getting a compile error: type mismatch when it tries to run through Const FLDR_PATH As String

Comment: That code compiles fine for me - just re-tested.  Are you sure it's that line?

Comment: Yes, I get that error and Sub SearchFolders() is highlighted

Comment: Do you maybe have a Global constant with the same name?  That's not the kind of line I'd expect to have a compile error.   If you copy just that line into a sub in a new workbook does it still error?

Comment: I deleted the \ from the end of FLDR_PATH and I no longer received an error message, but the code doesn't output anything? To get the code to search through the workbooks for the numbers I want, I was writing out the numbers in a different tab, highlighting them, and then clicking run. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: If you remove the terminating `\ ` then `strFile = Dir(FLDR_PATH & "*.xls*")` will likely find no matches.  It's difficult for me to offer help here, since I don't have your files for testing.  You'll need to step through the code and see exactly what's happening.  I added a few `Debug.Print` lines which might help.